# Can't remove the little islands when creating a svg map with kartograph.py

Tags: python, svg

I'm new to Python and to Kartograph. I'm using it to create a map of France, Italy, Portugal and Spain. But I don't want the little islands (mainly the French ones), causing the generation of a big useless map, for me.

I used a Python script to create my map ( thanks to rmbianchi ):

```
# file: makeMap.py
from kartograph import Kartograph
K = Kartograph()

def myfilter(record):
    return record['iso_a3'] in ["FRA","ITA","ESP","PRT"]


config = {
    "layers": {
        "FTC": {
            "src": "ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp",
            "filter": myfilter,
            "attributes": {"iso_a3":"iso_a3", "name":"name", "id":"iso_a3"},
        "bounds": {
    "mode": "polygons",
    "data": {
        "layer": "FTC",
        "filter": {
            "filter": ["ISO_A3", "in", ["FRA", "ITA", "ESP", "PRT"]]
        },
        "min-area": 0.50
    }
}
        }
    }, 
}

K.generate(config, outfile='ftc.svg')
```

But, little islands are still displayed, how can I avoid that?

Comment: Is all of France represented as a series of many polygons, or a single multipart polygon? You may need to split it up by parts.

Comment: your minimum area .50 is probably in the originating coord system. If that is degrees that may be where your problem is. Another method for filtering the islands may be with an attribute flag "if there is one" for island.

Comment: Thanks guys for the response. Jason, I don't know, can you maybe tell me how to get the information ?
Brad, I tried all numbers, and I have no result with it, I am pretty sure it's not coming from this. I used this informations in the doc : http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/#omitting-tiny-islands-in-boundary-calculation

Comment: The only way I found is to use a pan/zoom plugin... But I can't use the gps coordinates for my icons..